# How to set a specific attribute of an object if the object name is in a variable?

Tags: r, attributes

Normally you would set the attribute of an object as

```
attributes(x) <- list(dummy = 123)
```

But I have the variable names stored in a character vector. The following code throws an error:

```
var <- "x"
attributes(eval(as.name(var))) <- list(dummy = 123)
```

> Error in attributes(eval(as.name(var))) <- list(dummy = 123) : 
>     could not find function "eval<-"

If `eval(as.name())` is not the right way could someone suggest a way to solve this problem?

Comment: `class(eval(as.name(var)))` is `character`, whereas argument to `attribute(...)` should be an object, _not a character_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a function to apply the attributes and the assign function to apply them:

```
add_dummy <- function(obj, name, attribute){
  attr(obj, name) <- attribute
  return(obj)
}

assign(var, add_dummy(get(var), "attr_name", list(dummy = 123)))
```

Comment: your solution works fine for an atomic variable but converts a `dataframe` object to a `list`. Could you please modify the answer such that the `obj` returned does not change to a list; just the new attribute must be added to the object,

Comment: Ah, so you don't want to replace all attributes, you want to append one?

Comment: yes, and I managed to do it by assigning a specific attribute; I used `obj$attr_name<-attr_value` instead of  `attributes(obj) <- attribute` and my job is done. Thanks. Maybe you can add this part also in your answer so it becomes complete and useful in all situations.

Comment: I've modified my answer to allow modification rather than replacement of attributes